# Workflow for Git Noob: How to Work with Multiple Clones of a Repo

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I've used Git on and off, but we're making an effort to commit to it, so I'm needing some guidance.

I'm using JointsWP as my base for our WordPress themes. What I want to do is to clone a copy JointsWP, so I can pull updates from them, but not to push my own changes back to them. That I have no problem with, where I'm running into issues, is when I want to backup each theme we create as a separate repo on Github, to have a backup, and so we can share them as needed. When I clone the original JointsWP repo, I can't seem to figure out how to push change to my own new repo. I thought that a fork would be my answer, but I'm only allowed one fork of the original repo, and pulling updates to a fork makes it feel like that's not what they intended. I considered making a fork and branching off of my fork of the repo for each theme we're creating, but that's not really what branching is meant for.

I'm totally open to suggestions, I'd love to get my workflow right, and it's totally possible I'm thinking about this the wrong way. In summary, all I want is to make multiple WordPress themes, based on the JointsWP boilerplate theme, and be able to update those themes as the original JointsWP theme is updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that a **whole new repo** is what you're looking for.

I believe that a separate branch would be a simple solution to your problem.

create a new branch using

`git checkout -b new_theme`

And then you can have many branches in the same project. Then you can easily checkout each branch as needed using

`git checkout new_theme` or `git checkout old_theme`

Here, have a look [Git basic branching](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)